# Search values in a list from a file

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

word search on text file,  i need check whether a word appears in a large amount of files. Using a unique word my program works, I wanted to extend to a list of words using a list, however I can not make it work.

```
for name in files:
try:
    with open(name,errors='ignore') as f:
     found = "FALSE"
     pos = 0
     for line in f:
         pos = pos + 1
         if pattern_finder(line):
             found = "TRUE"
             break
     output_file.write (ntpath.basename(f.name) +';' + found + ';' + str(pos)+ ';' + line )
except IOError as exc:
    if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
        print("No Files Found")
        raise
output_file.close()



def pattern_finder (file_line):
    for i in range(len(pattern_to_find)):
        word = pattern_to_find[i]
        if word in file_line:
            return True
            break
```

The "word" in the line is never found, of course if I simply avoid the use of the list it works properly, i.e word="WORD_IM_LOOKING"
I believe I have a conceptual issue on how to obtain the value from the list to use that value see if exists in the list.index
can someone advice?
)

Comment: Your posted code fails to run for a variety of missing symbol definitions and indentation errors.  The output file (among other things) is superfluous to your problem.  Most of all, you should include a simple attempt to work with a list of target words -- this doesn't appear anywhere in your code or description.

Answer (score 0):

For this you'd want to use regex, and you can use `str.join` to compile a regex alternation pattern using the pipe char and your word list. Example:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    search_words = ['words', 'one', 'two']
    p = re.compile(r'|'.join(search_words), re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
    files_with_words = []
    for file in Path().glob('*.txt'):
        if p.search(file.read_text()):
            files_with_words.append(file.name)
    print(files_with_words)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT: updated to display the line number, position, and word found.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path


def main():
    search_words = ['words', 'one', 'two']
    p = re.compile(fr"\b({'|'.join(search_words)})\b", re.IGNORECASE)
    files_with_words = set()
    for file in Path().glob('*.txt'):
        with open(file.name) as f:
            for i, line in enumerate(f):
                re_search_obj = p.search(line)
                if re_search_obj:
                    print("file={}, line={}, pos={}, word={}".format(
                        file.name, i, re_search_obj.span(), re_search_obj.group()
                    ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Using regex is it possible to print which word was found and the  line # where the word appears?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that will print the file name, line, pos, and word.

Comment: Hi ! What is the set for ? Also, ignore case put everything in capitals?